# R - Histograms with shared scale

Tags: histogram

i need help:)

I would like to create a single graph that combines two histograms side by side. The key requirements are that the graph should present the frequency, and the x and y axes should have the same scales. I'm trying to achieve this using the ggarange function from the ggpubr package, but I'm facing difficulties. Can you please assist me in creating this combined histogram graph?"

library(ggpubr)

Create your histograms (hist1 and hist2)
hist1 <- ggplot(data = your_data, aes(x = variable1)) +
geom_histogram()

hist2 <- ggplot(data = your_data, aes(x = variable2)) +
geom_histogram()

Combine the histograms side by side with shared scales
combined_plots <- ggarrange(hist1, hist2, ncol = 2, common.legend = TRUE)

Display the combined plot
print(combined_plots)